# Identifying Elements on Alert selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, alert

I have an alert on this webpage that has elements I need to interact with other than what would be handled by **Accept()** or **Dismiss()**. Example, a **datagrid**, another **button**.

How do I do this?

Comment: `datagrid` and `another button`, I am quite confident it's not an _Alert_ but a _Modal Dialog Box_

Answer (score 0):

You can call `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` to switch the context to the alert.

Comment: I have tried, I just get error "modal dialog is present"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to an OS level dialogue window since you are not able to interact with it when you attempt to switch.  You will need to use something like AutoIT to work around this issue.

Here is a link to some info that may be helpful:

[Link](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/21/selenium-how-to-handle-windows-based-dialogs-and-pop-ups/)